# Cloud Dataflow job reading from BigQuery stuck before starting

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Cloud Dataflow job that's stuck in the initiation phase, before running any application logic. I tested this by adding a log output statement inside inside the `processElement` step, but it's not appearing in the logs so it seems it's not being reached.

All I can see in the logs are the following messages, this which appears every minute:

`logger: Starting supervisor: /etc/supervisor/supervisord_watcher.sh: line 36: /proc//oom_score_adj: Permission denied`

And these which loop every few seconds:

`VM is healthy? true.`

`http: TLS handshake error from 172.17.0.1:38335: EOF`

`Job is in state JOB_STATE_RUNNING, will check again in 30 seconds.`

The job ID is `2015-09-14_06_30_22-15275884222662398973`, though I have an additional two jobs (`2015-09-14_05_59_30-11021392791304643671`, `2015-09-14_06_08_41-3621035073455045662`) that I started the morning and which have the same problem.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Comment: All the worker log messages are expected and consistent with normal operation. So they don't explain why your job is stuck.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I suspect the problem is with the construction of the job itself, which loops through a bunch of data and calls ProcessContext.output() a lot. Probably not the ideal way to have written it.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "loops through a bunch of data and calls `output()`? If the data is coming in from the input to the `DoFn` this shouldn't be a problem (since it happens on the worker, after construction of the job). Or is the data coming from a field in a `DoFn` or somehow being serialized to the worker some other way?

Comment: The job itself runs through approximately 50 million rows from a BigQuery table, then for each row it runs `output()` about 300 times.

Comment: To clarify: 50 million rows is the input to the `DoFn`, but within the `DoFn` there's a for-each loop that runs through a simple array data structure of +- 300 elements and outputs a result for most of them. So the `DoFn` itself outputs +-300 `TableRow` instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like your pipeline has a BigQuery source followed by a `DoFn`. Before running your `DoFn` (and therefore reaching your print statement) the pipeline runs a BigQuery export job to create a snapshot of the data in GCS. This ensures that the pipeline gets a consistent view of the data contained in the BigQuery tables.

It seems like this BigQuery export job for your table took a long time. There unfortunately isn't a progress indicator for the export process. If you run the pipeline again and let it run longer, the export process should complete and then your `DoFn` will start running.

We are looking into improving the user experience of the export job as well as figuring out why it took longer than we expected.

Comment: Thanks Ben, that makes sense. One of the runs took just over two hours without showing any apparent activity though, which seems a bit long for a table of that size.

Comment: You could test the time it takes to materialize to GCS by going to BigQuery, selecting the table and selecting "Export Table", selecting "JSON (Newline Delimited)" as the format, and giving it a path to a Cloud Storage directory. This should mimic the export job that Dataflow executes.

Is this table materialized from a query result? We've seen jobs like this take around 2 hours on tables of the size you describe. We're looking at ways to improve both the performance and the indication that something is happening.

Comment: Ah, ok. An export I did on the table earlier today did seem to run for about that long. Thanks again.